# NSCore - How do I change Ble device name? (bluetooth-plugin by Eddy Verbruggen)

Tags: javascript, bluetooth-lowenergy, nativescript

I'm trying to create an app with a function that will change the device name of a certain paired peripheric. The protocol that was sent to me doesn't tell me what type of data is sent to that peripheric to be able to change that. On the firmware of that peripheric, you have a file called gatt.xml which has this information about this:

```xml
      <characteristic id="device_name" name="Device Name" sourceId="org.bluetooth.characteristic.gap.device_name" uuid="2A00">
      <informativeText/>
      <value length="32" type="utf-8" variable_length="true">smartFan</value>
      <properties read="true" read_requirement="mandatory" write="true" write_no_response="true" write_no_response_requirement="optional" authenticated_write="true"/>
    </characteristic>
```

So its possible to write and the type is utf8, so it should take a string encoded in utf-8, right?
I tried to make sure that my string is utf-8 but I get an error of invalid value. 
Here's what I tried to do:

```
    function checkUTF8(text) {
    var utf8Text = text;
    try {
        // Try to convert to utf-8
        utf8Text = decodeURIComponent(escape(text));
        // If the conversion succeeds, text is not utf-8
    }catch(e) {
        console.log(e.message); // URI malformed
        // This exception means text is utf-8
    }   
    return utf8Text; // returned text is always utf-8
}

function writeName() {
    var nameToFanDecoded = Buffer.from(deviceName.get("deviceName"),"utf8");

    var nameToFan = checkUTF8(nameToFanDecoded);

    ble.write({
        peripheralUUID: peripheral.UUID,
        serviceUUID: '1800',
        characteristicUUID: '2A00',
        value: nameToFan

    }).then(function (result) {

        console.log(typeof(nameToFan) + " " + nameToFan + "SUCCESS");


    }, function (err) {
        console.log("write error: " + err);
    });
}
```

Comment: I don't think you are allowed to change the name, it's read only.

Comment: well, that would be weird, because as you can see on the gatt.xml write="true", so it should be writable...